# LSTM/RNN many to one

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, lstm

I have the below dataset for a chemical process comprised of 5 consecutive input vectors to produce 1 output. Each input is sampled every minute while the output os sample every 5.

[image: dataset]

While I believe the output depends on the 5 previous input vectors, than I decided to look for LSTMs for my design. After a lot of research on how should be my LSTM architecture, I concluded that I should mask some of the output sequence by zeros and only leave the last output. The final architecture is below according to my dataset:

[image: lstm architecture]

My question is: What should be my 3D input tensor parameters? E.g. [5, 5, ?]? And also what should be my "Batch size"? Should it be the quantity of my samples?

Comment: Hi @Leb_Broth did you come with a solution to this? I think the problem I'm dealing with, is quite similar to this.

Comment: @FranciscoParrilla i remember that the correct answer below fixed my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are going for many to one sequence modelling, you don't need to pad zeros to your output (it's not needed). The easiest thing would be to perform classification at last time-step i.e after RNN/LSTM sees the 5th input. The dimension of your 3D input tensor will be [batch_size, sequence_length, input_dimensionality], where sequence_length is 5 in your case (row 1-5, 7-11, 13-17 etc.), and input_dimensionality is also 5 (i.e. column A- E).
[Batch_size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) depends on the number of examples (also how much reliable is your data), if you have more than 10,000 examples then batch size of 30-50 should be okay (read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140811/how-large-should-the-batch-size-be-for-stochastic-gradient-descent) explanation about choosing the appropriate batch size).

Comment: Do you mean that I should include a softmax classifier at the last time-step? Is there a sample code for that?

Comment: yes, you should have a softmax classifier at the last time-step. [This](https://github.com/uyaseen/theano-recurrence/blob/master/model/rnn.py) might be a good starting point (if you settle on [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), you just have to move `T.nnet.softmax(..)` outside scan. Also, this is simple rnn without batch, but it's trivial to add.

Comment: May be should start with [Keras](https://keras.io/), [This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) example does exactly what you want to achieve (you just have to provide data in the correct format).

Comment: thanks a lot ill check it and also I found this tutorial based on TensorFlow monik.in/a-noobs-guide-to-implementating-rnn-lstm-using-tensorflow/  but still figuring out how to declare and pass my dataset as I'm new to TensorFlow. It has a Softmax at the last time steps as u suggested previously.

Comment: hello yaseen, is it ok if my softmax classifier is equal to a Y_train_hot_encoded classes list?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand your question, I just noticed that since you are doing [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) (i.e your predictions are real values not class labels), it's probably not a good idea to use [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) (as it assigns probability to each class label), your output layer should not contain any non-linearity, just a linear weighted sum of activations should be enough. Also do take care of your pre-processing as well (normalize it properly)

Comment: [This](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/) and [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) should be helpful.

Comment: thanks Yaseen for your reply. Actually yes, I thought my problem was about regression because i thought it's a problem that deals with numbers inly. But then i saw a Tensorflow LSTM for MNIST classification: it takes a MNIST digit as a 28 x 28 sequence and use softmax for the labels. My problem is very similar, a 30 x 16 image where the images are totally independent from each other: actually it's not a real image, but a consecutive sequences of vectors that could be treated as such. I think i need to rescale them between -1 and 1 also. Thanks again.

Comment: @uyaseen thanks for the reply and thanks for your discussion. I am wondering how the pre-processing is done. In this case, say z-score standardization is performed, should I perform the normalization column-wisely (from A to E for the three samples which are row1-5, row7-11 and row13-17, respectively), to have each feature normalized through its timeframes, or perform it row-wisely to have each timeframe normalized?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the previous answer, I would say that you do not have to do a many-to-one architecture. It really depends on the problem you have. For example, if you system has a lot of dependencies from the past, i.e. more that 5 samples in your case, it would be better to do many-to-many architecture but with different input and output frequencies. But if you think that the previous 5 samples do not impact your next 5 samples. then a many-to-one architecture would do it.

Also, if you your problem is regression, you can use a Dense layer as the output of an LSTM cell is a tanh with output range of (-1, 1).

Comment: Hi! I don't think it's clear what you mean by "it idepends on the problem you have". The problem is quite clear, and the question assumes some interactions from the past and the architecture seems to be decided on already. The actual question is about the shape of the tensors and batchs ;)

Comment: I see your point. "some interactions from the past" is the key point I referring too. If the output is depends on more than 5 sequences on the past, the proposed architecture is not the right architecture for this problem. In addition, this seems to be a regression problem and thus needs a dense output not a softmax that has been discussed in the comments.

Comment: Basically, for future readers, if you have 1 output per every 5 input values, chopping the data every 5 samples and using a many-to-one architecture is not necessarily going to give the best performance.

Comment: Agreed, I see your points about the architecture and delays, and I think they're correct, or at least worth careful consideration. I imagine, though, that the point why your answer was downvoted was that it does not directly address the question posed. For future cases, consider making comments instead, when you're not answering the concrete question asked. Cheers, and welcome again to the site!

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks.

Comment: An example for the case mentioned would be a simple delay function, like y(t)=x(t-6). LSTM would never get this pattern if the data is chopped every 5 samples.